# "Can't set up device" It's missing components or corrupted

Tags: android, kiosk, android-management-api

I'm trying to enroll device with device owner app. I've tried to edit the QR code. Also I calculated the checksum using

```
apksigner verify --print-certs C:\Users\Mert\Desktop\myapp.apk
```

but I got the corrupted error.

Here my QR,

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME":"**com.test.testapp/.KioskAdminReceiver**",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM":"**Njc4YTFhYWI4ZTE4OWNkNWNhODhlMzJiYmQ1YmQ3MzUxZDE2MjhiZg==**",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION":"**https location**",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN": "**TOKEN**"}
}
```

Besides that,
I've tried to add download link of my app that in play store(close test). This also fails.

How can I make my app device owner during the device provision?

Answer (score 0):

There are number of reasons why you may be getting this error:

If you are integrating with **AMAPI SDK | Android Management API**

The QR code bundle includes the download location of Android Device Policy and an enrollment token.

```
{
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "I5YvS0O5hXY46mb01BlRjq4oJJGs2kuUcHvVkAPEXlg",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{
        "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN": "{enrollment-token}"
    }
}
```

> “Note: The values in QR code configuration do not require the *.”

These fields are used to download the ADP (Android Device Policy) which is used by AMAPI.

However, you can use the [AMAPI extensibility SDK](https://developers.google.com/android/management/extensibility-sdk-integration). This enables an EMM-specific extension app to communicate directly with ADP (Android Device Policy).

Please refer to this links for more information
https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#about_qr_codes
https://developers.google.com/android/management/extensibility-sdk-integration#policy_configuration

Comment: Thanks for reply @rey-v-aquino. I'm using AMAPI reference page to create enterprise and enrollment token. I would like to use the app that I upload play store. Since we cannot publish the app we need to use it in closed test. I found that we can use it as managed app (I pass enterpise Id as organization). But when I put the given link to download_location it does not download it and gives Could not download the app error. My question is what download_location should be used to download from play store(closed test) and should I apply policy for that ?